# Can store and retrieve Object Django BinaryField in SQLite but not MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I have some implementation that is best served by pickling a pandas dataframe and storing it in a DB.
This works fine if the database is sqlite but fails with a load error when it is MySQL
I have found other people with similar issues on stackoverflow and google but it seems that everybodys solution is to use sql to store the dataframe. 
As a last resort I would go down that route but it would be a shame for this use case to do that.
Anybody got a solution to get the same behaviour from mysql as sqlite here?

I simply dump the dataframe with

```
pickledframe = pickle.dumps(frame)
```

and store pickledframe as a BinaryField

```
pickledframe = models.BinaryField(null=True)
```

I load it in with

```
unpickled = pickle.loads(pickledframe)
```

with sqlite it works fine, with mysql I get

```
Exception Type: UnpicklingError
Exception Value:      invalid load key, ','.
```

upon trying to load it. 
Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth with Django 2.0.5, mysqlclient 1.3.12 and pandas on python 3.6, I can't reproduce this. Pickling a pandas dataframe worked just fine as did unpickling it, so perhaps this is a more particular interaction than just sqlite vs mysql.

Comment: Thanks. That is very useful information. I will see if the people hosting my database are doing anything unusual with settings or anything. I hope to update this with a solution.